# Full Calendar - How get year and month after click on prev or next button?

Tags: fullcalendar

I use **Full Calendar** in my project and I need to get year and month when I click on **Prev** or **Next** button.

This is my code, but doesn't work !! It return alway the current date.

```
            $('body').on('click', 'button.fc-prev-button', function () {
                var tglCurrent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var year = moment(tglCurrent).format('YYYY');
                var month = moment(tglCurrent).format('MM');
                alert('Year is '+year+' Month is '+month);
            });

            $('body').on('click', 'button.fc-next-button', function () {
                var tglCurrent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var year = moment(tglCurrent).format('YYYY');
                var month = moment(tglCurrent).format('MM');
                alert('Year is ' + year + ' Month is ' + month);
            });
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Try waiting until the view is actually rendered. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewRender

Comment: BTW `moment(tglCurrent)` is redundant because `tglCurrent` is already a moment object. `tglCurrent.format("YYYY")` will do the same job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it in below way

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button.fc-prev-button', function () {
                var tglCurrent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var date = new Date(tglCurrent);
                var year = date.getYear();
                var month = date.getMonth();
                alert('Year is '+year+' Month is '+month);
            });
```